# R: Filtering a data frame using another data frame

Tags: r

I am currently working in R using Rstudio. I am doing some VaR models and then i will perform a backtest on them. I have now done a VaR calculation performing a rolling window (fixed one) as the following:

```r
fit_st_dowjones <- function(x) { 
  fit_dstd_dowjones <- fitdist(x , 
                               dstd, 
                               start = list(mean = mean(x), sd = sd(x), nu = 2.5),
                               lower = c (-Inf , 0, 2),
                               upper = c (Inf, Inf, Inf),
                               control = list (trace = FALSE,
                                               report = TRUE,
                                               macxit = 1000)
                               )
  return(fit_dstd_dowjones$estimate)
}

    
rf_dstd_dow_jones <- function(dowjones_returns, rolling_window) {
  rwret_dstd_dowjones <- rollapply(dowjones_returns$ret, 
                                   width = rolling_window, 
                                   FUN = fit_st_dowjones)
  rwdates_dstd_dowjones <- rollapply(dowjones_returns$Date, 
                                     width = rolling_window, 
                                     FUN = function(x) x[length(x)])
  result_dstd_dowjones <- bind_cols(as_data_frame(rwdates_dstd_dowjones), 
                                    as_data_frame(rwret_dstd_dowjones))
  return(result_dstd_dowjones)
}
    
rw_dstd_dowjones <- rf_dstd_dow_jones(dowjones_returns, rolling_window = 2500)
```

And calculated the VaR as:

```
var_rw_dstd_dowjones <- rw_dstd_dowjones %>% 
  mutate(var_dstd_dowjones = qstd(0.05, mean = mean, sd = sd, nu = nu))
```

Right now i want to perform a bactest using the `VaRTest` from the package `rugarch` but I need the values of the data frame from the actual returns to match the ones on the data frame of the rolling window VaR estimation in order to compare them.

The two data frames i need to match are the following:

```
> head(var_rw_dstd_dowjones)
# A tibble: 6 × 5
       value          mean          sd       nu var_dstd_dowjones
       <chr>         <dbl>       <dbl>    <dbl>             <dbl>
1 26-06-1975 -6.201075e-05 0.008824476 4.357486       -0.01357950
2 27-06-1975 -6.456846e-05 0.008826638 4.350107       -0.01358159
3 30-06-1975 -6.546042e-05 0.008824543 4.355752       -0.01358217
4 01-07-1975 -6.817885e-05 0.008826171 4.350462       -0.01358467
5 02-07-1975 -7.324408e-05 0.008827353 4.359455       -0.01359615
6 03-07-1975 -7.019445e-05 0.008823156 4.360549       -0.01358722
> head(dowjones_returns)
# A tibble: 6 × 4
        Date                 index  price          ret
       <chr>                 <chr>  <dbl>        <dbl>
1 05-01-1965 DOW_JONES_INDUSTRIALS 875.86  0.006990273
2 06-01-1965 DOW_JONES_INDUSTRIALS 879.68  0.004361428
3 07-01-1965 DOW_JONES_INDUSTRIALS 884.36  0.005320116
4 08-01-1965 DOW_JONES_INDUSTRIALS 882.60 -0.001990140
5 11-01-1965 DOW_JONES_INDUSTRIALS 883.22  0.000702470
6 12-01-1965 DOW_JONES_INDUSTRIALS 885.89  0.003023029
```

The packages that i am using:

```
library(readr)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(fBasics)
library(fitdistrplus)
library(fGarch)
library(actuar)
library(zoo)
library(rugarch)
```

And what i want to acomplish:

```
VaRTest(alpha = 0.05, actual = dowjones_returns$ret, 
        VaR = var_rw_dstd_dowjones$var_dstd_dowjones, conf.level = 0.95)
```

and the error message:

> Error in VaRTest(alpha = 0.05, actual = dowjones_returns$ret, VaR = var_rw_dstd_dowjones$var_dstd_dowjones,:
> length of realized not equal to length of VaR!

Comment: I can't understand exactly what do you need to match in the two dataframes.

Comment: Please include the names of the packages that you are using in your question. A tibble is not a base R "object" and using `%>%` in base R throws and error.

Comment: I want to perform a VaR unconditional coverage test, using:
> VaRTest(alpha = 0.05, actual =  dowjones_returns$ret, VaR = var_rw_dstd_dowjones$var_dstd_dowjones, conf.level = 0.95)

But i get this error message:
Error in VaRTest(alpha = 0.05, actual = dowjones_returns$ret, VaR = var_rw_dstd_dowjones$var_dstd_dowjones,  : 
  
length of realized not equal to length of VaR!